# rxjs: how to do conditional judgement in observable flow

Tags: rxjs, flow-control

In my Angular project, I came into one case as following: 
  In the Frontend side I have a language system, user can choose one language from the options. And each time user choose a new language I need to invoke a server side method `subscribe` with it, and if the invoke run successfully, it will return to a `subscriptionid`. 
  Next time, when user change a new language, I need to create a new subscription. But before that, I need to `unsubscribe` the current one. The demo code goes as following:

```
  this.start().subscribe((res) => {
    // store current subscription id   
    this.currentSubscriptionId = res.SubscriptionId;
  });

  private start(): Observable<{ [key: string]: string }> {
      return this.xService.language$.pipe(
          switchMap((language) =>
            this.unsubscribe().pipe(
              switchMap((_) => this.invoke("subscribe",language)) // this.invoke return observable<any>
            )
          )
      );
  }

  private unsubscribe(): Observable<any> {
    if (this.currentSubscriptionId) { // default initial value is empty string  ""
      return this.invoke("Unsubscribe", {
        Id: this.currentSubscriptionId
      });
    } else {
      return of("");
    }
  }
```

so i use a state variable `currentSubscriptionId` for this flow. It's default value is empty string, so for the first time, no need to invoke the `unsubscribe` method, return an `of` observable.

in the current implementation, I capsulate the logic inside function of `unsubscribe` and based on the state variable `currentSubscriptionId` to handle the flow.

is there any other optimized solution for this case? do this kind of judgement control in a more RxJS style.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's time to utilize the "finalize" operator, which invokes the given function as its subscription gets disposed.

```js
const { Subscription, BehaviorSubject, Observable, of, never, interval } = rxjs;

const Rx = rxjs.operators;

let cleanUp = new Subscription();

function start() {
  return selectedLang.pipe(
    Rx.switchMap(lang => callSubscribeAPI(lang)),
    Rx.switchMap(id =>
      never().pipe(
        Rx.startWith(id),
        Rx.finalize(() => cleanUp.add(callUnsubscribeAPI(id).subscribe()))
      )
    )
  )
}

// Mock of language selection UI:

let selectedLang = new BehaviorSubject("ja");

// Server-side API mocks:

let subscriptionIdCounter = 0;

function callSubscribeAPI(lang) {
  let id = ++ subscriptionIdCounter;
  console.log(`[server] subscribe: ${lang}@${id}`);
  return of(`${id}`);
}

function callUnsubscribeAPI(id) {
  console.log(`[server] unsubscribe: ${id}`);
  return of();
}

// Usage:

start().subscribe(console.log);

interval(300)
 .pipe(Rx.take(4))
 .subscribe(i => 
   selectedLang.next(["en", "kr", "cn", "ja"][i])
 );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.4/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```